# how to insert database value into a text box using php

Tags: php, html

i want to know how to insert sql values into a text box within a table is it possible? tried several codes but doesn't seem to work here's my latest code

```
print "<td>" .<input type = "text" name = "text" value = "<?php print $row["Quantity"]; ?>" />. "</td>";
```

Comment: Google PHP print string syntax. You're almost there just that the syntax is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some weird/invalid formatting you have there. Assuming the value from the database is actually in `$row['Quantity']`, you should try this:

```php
print '<td><input type="text" name="text" value="' . $row["Quantity"] . '"</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax correction

```
 print '<td> <input type = "text" name = "text" value = "'.$row["Quantity"].'" /></td>';
```